# Resetting Pyomo model after computation

Tags: linear-programming, python, pyomo

I am aware that the types provided by pyomo are immutable and often cause issues when we feed the same data twice in consecutive computations (e.g. when trying to solve an instance a couple of times) What is the best way to reset model parameters after solving?

In my case, I use a model which I need to solve several times with minor changes in the input that is fed to it. Solving the model does not seem to produce any errors but it outputs a warning saying

> WARNING ELEMENT already exists in Set Ordered ScalarSet.

I also noticed that the objective value gets updated by building on top of the previously calculated objective value. Does someone know a good way to fix this problem?

Comment: I think the answer here will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59102989/15417280

Comment: That is a very good suggestion. However, Is there a better way to do it? 

For example I am trying to use an Abstract model which creates a new instance. I then try to feed the data to the new instance but this approach also seems to provoke the warning. 

One thing I noticed was that providing warmstart=True to the solver removes the issue but I guess that is just because we instruct pyomo to re-use already existing values instead of the newly provided. My ultimate goal is to just make them mutable so I can update them when solving the model multiple times.